# Popup box where you enter variable in php?

Tags: php, variables, popup

I am trying to make an add/remove file script, and what I want is a script that makes a window pop up where I enter a string, which is saves to a variable. I searched for long without luck. How can I do this?

Comment: You cannot implement popups using php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible. PHP is a server-side language while JavaScript (where you *can* create such popups using `prompt()`) is a client-side language.

The easiest solution would be creating a HTML form containing a simple `<input>` element where the user enters the string. When submitting the form (using an `<input type="submit">` button) your PHP script (put its name in the `action` attribute of the `<form>`) receives the value and makes it available as `$_POST['whatever']` assuming you were using `method="POST"` in the form and `name="whatever"` for the text input.

Of course you can style that form using CSS so it looks a bit like the JavaScript `prompt()` dialog. Or you could actually use JavaScript and then put the value into a hidden field and submit the form using JavaScript. Or you could use AJAX. But the good old form is the easiest way to do it.

Comment: Sorry, i should have thought of that. Thanks for the help.